# Check 3 columns against each other in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a `SELECT` statement with 3 columns and want to compute a fourth column from them.

1. If Column1 has a value, then Column4 = Column1
2. If not 1. and Column2 has a value, then Column4 = Column2
3. If not 2. and Column3 has a value, then Column4 = Column3
4. If not 3. NULL

Basically, look from Column1 to Column2 if you find a value and put the first one into Column4.

I can do it with 2 columns easily:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN (Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 <> '') 
          THEN Column1 
          ELSE Column2 
    END 'Column4'
```

But I know of no way how to incorporate `Column3` into that logic. Only think I can think of right now is to store the result as a temptable or view and then do another `SELECT` that compares the found value with `Column3`.

**Important**: all 3 columns can have all possible combinations of string, NULL, ' ' or ''

Comment: *"Important: All 3 columns can have all possible combinations of String, `NULL`, `' `' or `''`"* I would personally, then, fix that data model too and no allow zero length strings in your data (and `UPDATE` the existing ones to `NULL`).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(Column1, ''), NULLIF(Column2, ''), NULLIF(Column3, ''), NULL) AS Column4...
```

[COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to NULL.

[NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(Column1, Column2, Column3) AS Column4
```

Update to handle ''

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(Column1, ''), NULLIF(Column2, ''), NULLIF(Column3, '')) AS Column4
```